# How to insert time only into a Rails database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to enter for example 15:00 as a time for a delivery collection.

My database table is as follows (so a user can specify a date and time separately):

```
create_table "collection_availabilities", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date "date"
  t.time "time"
end
```

How do I enter a time e.g. 15:00  in the database row?

```
cav1 = collection_availability.create(date: Date.parse(2001,2,3) time: ???????????)
```

Comment: How about https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_time?

Comment: Have you tried `"15:00"` as string?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Time.parse, here is the [link for reference](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html), but for your note you should use different field name for date and time field

```
cav1 = collection_availability.create(date_field: Date.parse("2001-2-3"), time_field: Time.parse("15:00"))
```

Comment: 2.3.3 :010 > cav1 = Availability.create(date: Date.parse(2001,2,3) time: Time.parse("15:00"))
SyntaxError: (irb):10: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')'
...ate: Date.parse(2001,2,3) time: Time.parse("15:00"))
...                               ^
(irb):10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input

Comment: Date.parse should be with string, Date.parse("2001-2-3"), you may check my edited answer